# How to merge two or more table from different databases to generate a report in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, report, reporting

I have two MySql and an Oracle database, i want to generate a report that want data from each of them,
i want customer info from one of them, service info from another and  invoice info from the last one.
is there anyway to import and merge data from different data sources in PowerBI?!

Thanks,

Comment: Yes, just connect and collect data from those sources and then you can merge both data based on relational column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are fairly new to PowerBI, here are the steps to take:

1. Use the Get Data feature on the toolbar to import from the source databases.
2. They will appear as tables in your PowerBI canvas.
3. Hit the Transform Data feature

[image]

4. Select a table and then Merge Queries feature
5. Select the table to merge
6. Select the column to merge on
7. Click Ok - and they will be emerged.

You will need to merge again in to your merged table to add the 3rd source table.

[image]